# Missed required argument request in parent::__construct call

Tags: magento2, php, module, construct

I'm working on a Magento module for the past month, and everything works great on my local machine. Then I decided to release the module as a beta and test it online in a newly installed store, and after installing it from CLI, I'm getting this error:

```
Werules\Chatbot\Block\Webhook\Messenger Missed required argument request in parent::__construct call. File: /htdocs/magento2/app/code/Werules/Chatbot/Block/Webhook/Messenger.php
```

Why is that happening? Here is the file `app/code/Werules/Chatbot/Block/Webhook/Messenger.php`

```
namespace Werules\Chatbot\Block\Webhook;

class Messenger extends \Werules\Chatbot\Block\Webhook\Index
{
    protected function processRequest()
    {
        // SOME CODE HERE
    }
}
```

and app/code/Werules/Chatbot/Block/Webhook/Index.php

```
namespace Werules\Chatbot\Block\Webhook;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_helper;
    protected $_chatbotAPI;
    protected $_messageModel;
    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $_define;
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Werules\Chatbot\Helper\Data $helperData,
        \Werules\Chatbot\Model\ChatbotAPI $chatbotAPI,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Werules\Chatbot\Model\MessageFactory $message
    )
    {
        $this->_helper = $helperData;
        $this->_chatbotAPI = $chatbotAPI;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_messageModel = $message;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->_define = new \Werules\Chatbot\Helper\Define;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? Thank you.

**EDIT:** I'm extending another block from my module, is that a bad thing? Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Did you delete `var/generation` first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is self-explained. You forgot to inject the arguments from the parent. `$context` and `$data` are mandatory.

app/code/Werules/Chatbot/Block/Webhook/Index.php

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, // parent argument
    ......
    array $data = [] // parent argument
) {
    ......
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
```

---

> I'm extending another block from my module, is that a bad thing? Maybe
>   this is the problem?

It's normal.

Comment: Thank you. So I'm missing the `data` array in the `Index` block? Because my `Messenger` block doesn't have a constructor

Comment: As I see, you're missing in `Index.php`

Comment: Is this `data` array required by Magento? Because I'm not using it in my code. For me it seems that what is missing is "the required argument `request` in parent::__construct", as I have a `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request` as parameter for my `Index` block.

Comment: `array $data = []` is required by the parent `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`. Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: It did work! Yay. Thanks. I was only able to test it this morning, sorry about that.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to make clear that the $data array is mandatory? To make it easier for other people to see.

Comment: @Pablo updated my answer. You can update my answer also.